# How to shorten my function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

Well, I know this is probably my another stupid question but I'm tired of looking for the answer and I'm not clever enough to figure it out myself.

My script looks like this and I wonder how can I make it shorter as there will be many more exercises like this. As you can see every function does the same thing. Possible answers are only three: 'is', 'are' and 'am'.

Anyone help please?

```
<p>1. He <input type="text" id="ex1.1" size="4"> funny. <input type="button" value="Check!" onclick="a()"> <span id="err1"></span></p>

<script>
function a() {
   var a=document.getElementById("ex1.1");
   if((a.value=="is")) {
      document.getElementById('err1').innerHTML= 'Correct!';
      document.getElementById('err1').style.color = "green";
   } else {
      document.getElementById('err1').innerHTML= 'Wrong :( Try again!';
      document.getElementById('err1').style.color = "red";
   }

}
</script>

<p>2. I <input type="text" id="ex1.2" size="4"> cool. <input type="button" value="Check!" onclick="b()"> <span id="err2"></span></p>
<script>

function b()
{
   var a=document.getElementById("ex1.2");
   if((a.value=="am")) {
      document.getElementById('err2').innerHTML= 'Correct!';
      document.getElementById('err2').style.color = "green";
   } else {
      document.getElementById('err2').innerHTML= 'Wrong :( Try again!';
      document.getElementById('err2').style.color = "red";
   }

}
</script>

<p>3. She <input type="text" id="ex1.3" size="4"> pretty. <input type="button" value="Check!" onclick="c()"> <span id="err3"></span></p>
<script>

function c() {
   var a=document.getElementById("ex1.3");
   if((a.value=="is")) {
      document.getElementById('err3').innerHTML= 'Correct!';
      document.getElementById('err3').style.color = "green";
   } else {
      document.getElementById('err3').innerHTML= 'Wrong :( Try again!';
      document.getElementById('err3').style.color = "red";
   }
}
</script>

<p>4. We <input type="text" id="ex1.4" size="4"> fast. <input type="button" value="Check!" onclick="d()"> <span id="err4"></span></p>
<script>

function d()
{
   var a=document.getElementById("ex1.4");
   if((a.value=="are")) {
      document.getElementById('err4').innerHTML= 'Correct!';
      document.getElementById('err4').style.color = "green";
   }  else {
      document.getElementById('err4').innerHTML= 'Wrong :( Try again!';
      document.getElementById('err4').style.color = "red";
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: "I'm not clever enough to figure it out myself." -- Found your problem. Step 1: Believe you can do something.

Comment: Also, if your code already works, perhaps it is better suited for CodeReview? (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I know but isn't this what this website is made for? To help?

Comment: You're exactly right, but you have to believe you can do it too; SO exists to guide you towards an answer -- not prove that you don't need to think about it. (Cue motivational soundtrack)

Comment: SO is to fix code not working whereas codereview is about how to improve working code.

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I feel a big urge to answer JQuery... now I just want to hit myself

Comment: @Sebastien To be fair, using jQuery would at least get rid of the inline event handlers, and potentially also permit DOM trivial traversal to find the necessary elements.

Comment: @Alnitak Check this out: http://zarjay.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: @Sebastien I use jQuery a lot, including authoring numerous plugins for that and jQuery UI (not published - internal use only).  I do though always ensure that I _don't_ use jQuery for stuff that is trivially done without it.  I automatically downvote any answer that uses `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `this.id`.

Comment: @Alnitak I sure that you do. In fact I do use it a lot (shame on me) I just couldn't resist doing the joke XD +1 to your answer

Answer (score 4):

There are only three things that change in each function - the element IDs and the desired answer - these should therefore be parameters.

You should also apply the *Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) Principle* within the function itself and avoid repeated unnecessary calls to `document.getElementById`

```
function checkAnswer(inputId, outputID, rightAnswer) {
    var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
    var output = document.getElementById(outputId);
    var correct = (input.value === answer);

    // remainder left as an exercise for the OP, except to
    // note that the code would be potentially shortened
    // even further with use of the ternary ?: operator
    // instead of an if/else branch
    ...
}
```

Example usage:

```
checkAnswer('ex1.2', 'err2', 'am')
```

Extracting common elements from a piece of code (and if necessary parameterising that code) is known as "refactoring".

You should note that element IDs with decimal points in are only permitted in HTML5.  You would be better using an underscore.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with your "unnecessarily defensive code" criticism. While in this case it could be considered overkill, coding defensively is a sound engineering principle and so is a good habit to get into, adds virtually no overhead *in most cases*, and will save you a ton of hurt when you most need it. I would much rather have coders work for me who waste a cycle here and there than those who "damn the torpedoes and full steam ahead" into bug-hell.

Comment: @RobRaisch well, it depends.  In this case, the _only_ reason the code can fail is due to programmer error, in which case error messages are exactly what you need and all the coder is doing by silencing the errors is making it _harder_ to debug the code.  It's a different matter if you're considering user inputs where programming defensively is exactly what you want (unless you program in Erlang...)

Comment: @RobRaisch or in other words, IMHO the object existence test in that answer's code is actually doing more harm than good.  That's what I meant by _unnecessarily_ defensive.

Answer (score 1):

You are using uncecessarily long calls to get objects, such as:

```
document.getElementById('err1');
```

You can shorten your code a lot by doing what you are doing with your `a` variable. Such as:

```
var err3 = document.getElementById('err3');
```

After that you can do:

```
if(a.value == "is") {
    err3.innerHTML= 'Correct!';
    err3.style.color = "green";
} else{
    err3.innerHTML= 'Wrong :( Try again!';
    err3.style.color = "red";
}
```

Also, notice that you have a function called `a`, and inside it a variable called `a`. Careful with that... It can be useful in some situations but given the kind of help you are asking for here, you probably should avoid giving a function and a variable inside it the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function displayMessage(inputId, messageId, valueToCheck) {
        var inputEle = document.getElementById(inputId),
            messageEle = document.getElementById(messageId);
        if (inputEle && messageEle) {
            if (inputEle.value == valueToCheck) {
                messageEle.innerHTML = 'Correct!';
                messageEle.style.color = "green";
            }
            else {
                messageEle.innerHTML = 'Wrong :( Try again!';
                messageEle.style.color = "red";
            }
        }
    }
```

Check this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7v7y5/

Comment: 3/10 - must try harder - no explanation and unnecessarily defensive code (in the event of the given elements not existing the browser will automatically create an error on the console, which those code prevents and silently ignores).

Comment: Damn...looks like I mistakenly commented on the wrong answer.